# How does ssh-keygen work?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, key-generator, ssh-keygen

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1070130) and understand that the I'm making a key that is held in a directory somewhere so that when I go to a website, it will automatically see my key and give me access without me having to sign in. Is that correct? what does the "-t" and "-C" mean? What does putting in my email do? Does that mean that when I go to a site, if I put in my email it will automatically have access to my ssh key?

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "yourname@yourdomain.ext"
```

Comment: `man ssh-keygen` is your friend

Answer (score 2):

First of all, whenever in doubt, consider checking MAN pages first.

In this case, [MAN page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) tells us that `-t rsa` sets the type of the key to RSA (or, generates the key using RSA algorithm). The MAN page also mentions that it's the default one, so if you don't put that in, it will still generate RSA key.

As for the `-C "yourname@yourdomain.ext"`, `-C` specifies a comment which will be put in the generated files that can help you identify the key later on (for whatever reason).

Keys don't work "automatically". Normally, you install your public key (NEVER share your private key - that's the purpose of it being private) on a remote machine, and then when you try logging on to it via SSH, there will be a series of challenge requests between the two that will result you being allowed to log on the instance without typing your password if your private key matches one of the installed remote public keys (there can be more than one if for example you install different public keys for every machine you log on from or have some sort of shared account).